# PopupWindow shifts when it's child ListView grows

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am trying to display contents of a ListView in a PopupWindow that grows as the List is populated. It works fine except that the elements shift as the list grows until it stops adding new elements. Is there a way to keep the position of the window fixed as it grows downward on the screen? I am new to Android programming so any input is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
private void initView(View v) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().
    getMetrics(displaymetrics);

    int width = (int) ((int)displaymetrics.widthPixels * 0.9);

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,width,
                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    m = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    m.layout_main.getForeground().setAlpha(220);

    btnScan = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.scan);

    btncancel = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.close);

    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);

    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);


    int loc_int[] = new int[2];
    if (v == null)

    try
    {
        v.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int);
    } catch (NullPointerException npe)
    {
        //when the view doesn't exist on screen anymore.

    }

    Rect location = new Rect();
    location.left = loc_int[0];
    location.top = loc_int[1] ;
    location.right = location.left + v.getWidth()/2;
    location.bottom = location.top - view2.getHeight()/2 ;


    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view2, Gravity.CENTER,
                               view2.getWidth()/2,  location.top);

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view2);

    listDevicesFound = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.devicelist);

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    adtDevice = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_text, 
                lsDevice);           

    listDevicesFound.setAdapter(adtDevice);

    listDevicesFound.setOnItemClickListener(new onIntemClick());



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the width and height of the window using a fraction of width and height obtained using: 
            DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            MyApplication.width = metrics.widthPixels;
            MyApplication.height = metrics.heightPixels;

With a fixed height the PopupWindow no more shifts with new additions to the List.